# iOS - Application crashed due to unknown error

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am working on table view and adding some labels in table row. And binding them values.

But my application suddenly crashes, even after executing whole tableview datasource code properly.

It gives following error.

Please help me to resolve this issue

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000023

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000023'

*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105003495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104d5799e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010509465d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ff4d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ff4938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x0000000103a817c5 -[UILabel _shadow] + 34
6   UIKit                               0x0000000103a829fd -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 81
7   UIKit                               0x0000000103a84ab2 -[UILabel drawRect:] + 100
8   UIKit                               0x00000001039604bd -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 474
9   QuartzCore                          0x000000010537d368 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 116
10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105281843 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2641
11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010537d274 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 59
12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010537d113 _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1461
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105372173 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 319
14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001053721f5 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 35
15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001052e5fb8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001052e7030 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001052e769d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fcedc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fced37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fae522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fadd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
22  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001073a1f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x0000000103900e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
24  CW4Members                          0x0000000102ed6023 main + 115
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105ed65c9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: place the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your value is of NSNumber type & u are assigning it to label and label takes it as NSString.You can either assign it by

```
cell.label.text =  [value stringValue];
```

or

```
cell.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value];
```